# how to send a value from a tag to another php file?

Tags: php, jquery, html

How can I send "url" in `a.php` to `b.php` when I click each list?

After that, I want to show `b.php`

I know these codes are wrong.

Thank you very much in advance!

**a.php**:

```
<ul class="list-group">

  <a id="navType1" class="list-group-item" value="url1">list 1</a>

  <a id="navType1" class="list-group-item" value="url2">list 2</a>

</ul>
```

**b.php**:

```
<script src="https://..." + url from a.php + "..."></script>
```

Comment: Id's need to be unique

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.list-group-item').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location = '/b.php?' + $(this).attr('value');
});
```

Comment: I changed your code a little, and it works!! Thank you very much!